# MLE of regression coefficients with non-constant variance

Tags: regression, machine-learning, variance, estimation, linear-model

In the simplest case of the statistical view of linear regression, we have that

$$
y = f(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{w}) + \nu, \text{ where }\nu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)
$$

where $\mathbf{x}$ is an input vecto, $\mathbf{w}$ the vector of the coefficients of the linear function $f$ and $\nu$ is so called "white noise". Finding the MLE for $\mathbf{w}$ is pretty much a standard procedure, no real tricks involved.

What I am wondering about is what happens in the following scenario

$$
y = f(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{w}) + \nu, \text{ where }\nu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^2)
$$

namely, when the variance $\sigma^2$ is a function of the input vector $\mathbf{x}$. In the case of constant variance, we create the likelihood function

$$
\displaystyle p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}_i; \mathbf{w}, \sigma^2) = \prod_{i}^{N}p(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i; \mathbf{w}, \sigma^2)
$$

and maximize it using standard techniques. Something like this does not seem to be possible under the new model with non-constant variance, since the variance is not really a fixed parameter of the model but rather a function of the input. It is also important to stress that **we do not know** the value of $\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}^2$ on each $\mathbf{x}$, we only know that it varies with $\mathbf{x}$.

Now, if we happen to know the variance on each input vector $\mathbf{x}_i$, we (I think) can use the exact same methodology as the case with constant variance, namely maximize:

$$
\displaystyle p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}_i; \mathbf{w}, \sigma) = \prod_{i}^{N}p(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i; \mathbf{w}, \sigma^2_{\mathbf{x}_i})
$$

I would appreciate comments on the following two questions:

1. Is the first problem solvable without using Bayesian methods or some very advanced estimation theory?
2. Am I missing something in the proposed solution for the case where we know the variance for each input vector?

Comment: You could start out by considering simpler variance functions such as $\sigma^2_{X}=X_1 \sigma^2$.  Not sure you can get too far considering all possible variance functions.  A Bayesian method would also need some specificity.

Comment: Is this different from generalized least squares?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a linear model and assume normally distributed errors. With constant variance you assume that $y_i$ is normally distributed but with different means for each individual, and that mean depends on some explanatory variables $x$. So you can write the distribution of $y_i$ as $y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma)$. This becomes solvable if we replace $\mu_i$ with $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \cdots+ \beta_k x_{ki}$ (as long as $k<N$.

You can follow the same logic with the residual variance. Now both $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ differ between individuals, and both depend on explanatory variable $x$ and $z$. $x$ and $z$ can be the same, overlapping, completely different. So $y_i$ is now distributed $y_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ and $\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \cdots+ \beta_k x_{ki}$, and $\sigma_i = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_{1i} + \gamma_2 x_{2i} + \cdots+ \gamma_k x_{ki}$. This might work, but this specification does not rule out negative variances. So it is safer to specify $\ln(\sigma_i) = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_{1i} + \gamma_2 x_{2i} + \cdots+ \gamma_k x_{ki}$

For example, this is how I would implement such a model on the fly in Stata. `mlexp` expects the log likelihood function, which is the log of the distribution of $y_i$, so that explains the `ln(normalden())` part. The first argument of `normalden()` is the dependent variabe, so that explains `mpg`.  The second and third arguments of `normalden` are the mean and the variance. Here `{some_name:var1 var2 _cons}` is short for $\beta_0 + \beta_1 var_1 + \beta_2 var_2$. The `some_name` is used for labeling, which is expecially important when the same variable is used in both the mean and the variance equation.

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. mlexp (ln(normalden(mpg , {xb:weight foreign _cons}, exp({lnsigma:foreign _cons}))))

initial:       log likelihood =     -<inf>  (could not be evaluated)
feasible:      log likelihood = -6441.8168
rescale:       log likelihood = -368.12496
rescale eq:    log likelihood =  -257.3948
Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  -257.3948  (not concave)
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -231.78128  (not concave)
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -226.86965  (not concave)
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -224.24518  (not concave)
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -198.21111
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -192.59299
Iteration 6:   log likelihood = -183.30713
Iteration 7:   log likelihood = -183.25379
Iteration 8:   log likelihood = -183.25373
Iteration 9:   log likelihood = -183.25373

Maximum likelihood estimation

Log likelihood = -183.25373                     Number of obs     =         74

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
xb           |
      weight |  -.0061135   .0004522   -13.52   0.000    -.0069998   -.0052272
     foreign |  -1.175046   1.211334    -0.97   0.332    -3.549217    1.199126
       _cons |   40.10603   1.532606    26.17   0.000     37.10217    43.10988
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
lnsigma      |
     foreign |   .8022486   .1808845     4.44   0.000     .4477215    1.156776
       _cons |    .818957   .0982276     8.34   0.000     .6264344     1.01148
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```